# Does this prove one statement implies the other?

Tags: proof-verification, logic, proof-writing

Statement $A$

$∀a,b,c∈ℤ,a<b<c⇒a+b+c<3c$

Statement $B$

$∀x,y,z∈ℤ,x<y∧z≠x∧z≠y⇒x+y+z<3z$

Am I allowed to say that $A$ implies $B$ by letting $z$ from $B$ equal the $c$ in $A$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your argument *doesn't* work: there is no reason we can treat $z$ as $c$, since in $A$ it is required that $c$ be the greatest element of the three, and all $B$ requires is that $z$ be different from $x$ and $y$. So that doesn't work. For example, maybe $z$ is the *smallest* of the three numbers.

*(EDIT: Wow, I'm bad at reading comprehension; blatantly false statement removed.)*

In fact, we can tell that the two statements *aren't* equivalent, since the first is true and the second is false.

Comment: I get that the second statement is false, but why is the first one false?

Comment: @user66590 It's not false, I just wildly misread it. Sorry!